# Apache config with flask, wsgi, and reverse proxy

Tags: flask, apache2, mod-wsgi

Below is my Apache config.  What I am trying to do have a reverse proxy set up for the main part of the site.  So when users go to mysite.xyz, they get what is running on port 5000 (this is working).  I also want to run a flask app on mysite.xyz/page1  This is coming back with a 404 not found page.  When I switch them and put the app at / and put the main site at page1, then the app works but page1 can't find any of the correct js assets so I'd like to avoid that.  But the app does work and works on apache but the reverse proxy must be over-riding the WSGI deployment of the flask app or something?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName mysite.xyz
    ServerAdmin email@gmail.com

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mysite\.xyz$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [L,R=301]

    WSGIScriptAlias /page1 /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp.wsgi
    <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ProxyPass`, try:

```
RewriteRule ^/$ http://127.0.0.1:5000/ [P]
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is stale but it may help someone. Flask hates reverse proxy. You need to add flask-reverse-proxy-fix to your app.

https://pypi.org/project/flask-reverse-proxy-fix/